# No current row message appears while getting Max values from SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to get max value form database if database not empty. Program works fine but it gives **No Current Row message** on start. I've query like this,

```
 public int GetMaxValue(String table, String column, int columnIndex)
        {
            try
            {
                int values = -1;

                String query = "SELECT MAX(" + column + ") FROM " + table;
                SQLiteCommand sQLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, sQLiteConnection);
                sQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                using (SQLiteDataReader sQLiteDataReader = sQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (!sQLiteDataReader.IsDBNull(0))
                    {
                        while (sQLiteDataReader.Read())
                        {
                            values = sQLiteDataReader.GetInt32(columnIndex);
                            sQLiteDataReader.Close();
                            return values;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

and call this method by,

```
string orderNo = database.GetMaxValue(Database.TABLE_ORDER, Database.INVOICE_NO_ORDER, 0).ToString();
```

in above function, i've check already if Reader Null then do not continue by this,

```
 if (!sQLiteDataReader.IsDBNull(0))

                    }
```

but its not works. Kindly tell how to get rid of **No Current Row message**

Comment: Check sQLiteDataReader.HasRows before attempting to read, however .ExecuteScalar() will simplify this code greatly.

Comment: by HasRows, it gives message "Specify cast not valid"

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem

```
public Int32 GetMaxValue(String table, String column, int columnIndex)
        {
            try
            {
                Int32 values = -1;

                String query = "SELECT MAX(" + column + ") FROM " + table;
                SQLiteCommand sQLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, sQLiteConnection);
                sQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                using (SQLiteDataReader sQLiteDataReader = sQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sQLiteDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        while (sQLiteDataReader.Read())
                        {
                            values = sQLiteDataReader.GetInt32(columnIndex);
                            return values;
                        }
                    }

                    sQLiteDataReader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return -1;
        }
```